# Understanding Node Streams sequence of operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I am learning about Node Streams using Stream-Adventure (https://github.com/substack/stream-adventure).
I'm having a hard time understanding the HTML-Stream Lesson.

This is the challenge :

> Your program will get some html written to stdin. Convert all the
>   inner html to upper-case for elements with a class name of "loud".
>
> You can use `trumpet` and `through` to solve this adventure.

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/jeremy-w/node-stream-adventure-solutions/blob/master/html-stream.js) :

```
var trumpet = require('trumpet');
var through = require('through');
var to_upper = function (buffer) {
  this.queue(buffer.toString().toUpperCase())
};
var tr = trumpet();

// Here I expect the output to stdout to have printed as is.
process.stdin.pipe(tr).pipe(process.stdout);

// In the below lines, there is no reference to the above stream 
// which should have already started to send to stdout.
// How are the lines below modifying the above stream?
var stream = tr.select('.loud').createStream()
stream.pipe(through(to_upper)).pipe(stream)
```

I cannot seem to understand the program flow above.

How do the last two lines modify the stream output, even though there is no reference/callbacks to use the above stream?

Comment: I'm not familiar it, but wouldn't be 'tr' already piped to process.stdin?

Comment: There is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103981/how-does-piping-a-stream-back-to-itself-work-with-trumpet), and a [discussion](https://github.com/nodeschool/discussions/issues/346)

Answer (score 0):

The key is to think asynchronously. Think of `process.stdin.pipe(tr).pipe(process.stdout)` as 'take the input put it through tr, which we'll elaborate on later, and print to stdout'.

Then below we fill out the logic and say exactly what `tr` will be doing to the input. There is only one `tr` object in this program. And the `stream` object is defined in terms of it. The code using `stream` at the bottom is manipulating the same `tr` being used to filter `stdin` and `stdout`.
Remember the hint *Now `stream` outputs all the inner html content at `'.beep'` and the data you write to `stream` will appear as the new inner html content.* That's exactly what the last line is doing.