# How does piping a stream back to itself work with Trumpet?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Learning node.js.  Trumpet works by piping a stream back to itself, apparently, so the processed data can then be output.  This makes no sense to me, since it seems to be like connecting both ends of a stream to itself.  How does trumpet distinguish between the pre and post processed data?  ie, why doesn't `loud.pipe(...).pipe(loud)` result in some form of infinite loop of processing?

```
var trumpet = require('trumpet');
var through = require('through');
var tr = trumpet();

var loud = tr.select('.loud').createStream();
loud.pipe(through(function (buf) {
    this.queue(buf.toString().toUpperCase());
})).pipe(loud);

process.stdin.pipe(tr).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the exact same confusion:

**davecocoa** had this to say to me at the nodeschool.io discussions thread on github.
Below is an extract from https://github.com/nodeschool/discussions/issues/346

---

I think you might be confusing the two streams `loud` and `tr`.

`tr` is the main trumpet stream

- It is a transform stream (has input and output like a pipe)
- It takes html as input
- It outputs html
- we connect `stdin` to its input, and we connect its output to `stdout`

We created `loud` by asking `tr` to select html elements with class loud

- It is a duplex stream (has input and output like a telephone)
- it outputs or sends html elements
- it also receives html elements

`tr` behaves such that, when html is streamed to it, if there are elements with class loud, they are output from `loud`, which sends them to the through stream you built for making the text uppercase, which sends them to back to `loud`'s input, where they are reinserted into the html `tr` originally received and output from `tr`.

I guess an important thing to note is that, although `loud` has an important connection with `tr`, they are not actually piped together at all.

---

Comment: This is a great explanation! Could you contribute to the trumpet documentation?

Answer (score 3):

I was confused too and i would express it again with my words:

`tr.select('.loud').createStream()` creates a Duplex-Stream which is nothing else than a combined `ReadStream` and `WriteStream`

This Stream recieves all *matches* in its ReadStream.
If you write to the WriteStream, trumpet takes it as *match-replace*

This works for me in the same way:

```js
// create trumpet stream
var tr = trumpet();

// create stream with selected elems
var trumpetSelector = tr.select('.loud');
var upperOut = trumpetSelector.createReadStream();
var upperIn = trumpetSelector.createWriteStream();
upperOut.pipe(new UpperCaseTransformer()).pipe(upperIn);
```

***Please correct me if i'm wrong!***